# What Android emulators for Windows enable a webcam to be used as a front camera?

Tags: windows, android, emulator

At the moment I'm using Bluestacks to run Android apps, but it doesn't have the ability to emulate the front camera using a webcam.

Are there Windows Android emulators which can do this?

Comment: The [one from Google](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) that comes bundled with eclipse has options for it - see [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-camera-in-android-emulator/) - but I haven't used it with a webcam personally, so I am not sure if it works or not. Alternatively you might just want to virtualize the x86 version of android and assign it the webcam via your virtualization program, see [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/)

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin Android Player

Are you into hard core mobile app development and looking for an android phone simulator? Yes! Xamarin Android Player is the definitive tool for you if you work with visual studio or Xamarin Studio.

It offers a native user interface on both windows and Mac and is one of the most sophisticated android emulators for developing and testing android apps.

Xamarin Android Player runs Android on x86 and utilizes open GL and hardware accelerated virtualization which makes is significantly faster than the stock android emulator.

Some of the key features include battery simulator, location simulator and webcam utilization as front and back cameras.

Read more about Xamarin Android Player here at - 
https://www.xamarin.com/